# How do I output performance times for rake tasks

Tags: .net, ruby, rake

I'm working on rake tasks for a large .net solution (using the albacore gem) and I want to be able to record to a file start and stop times for any rake tasks that run to try and speed up our build and locate bottlenecks. Is there anything built in that I can use, or do I need to write something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple benchmarking library in Ruby's Stdlib:

```
require 'benchmark'

puts Benchmark.measure { "a"*1_000_000 }
```

You could drop that in your rake tasks, as for an automatic "benchmark all rake task executions", that would take a little digging into the innards of rake.

More info at: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Ended up writing this: [rake-performance](http://rubygems.org/gems/rake-performance)